# React keep focus onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, onblur, onfocus

I have a component that trigger `focus()` on ref component during `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. Also I have functionality that do not fire onClose when we click outside. When I click outside `onBlur` I trigger again `focus` to keep focus on element. What is the best approach? and why in some cases I saw that better use setTimeout onblur?

```
export class Test extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => this.focusContainer()
    componentDidUpdate = () => this.focusContainer()

    container = React.createRef()
    focusContainer = () => this.container.current.focus()

    render = () => {
       return (
         <div
                style={{outline: 'none'}}
                onKeyPress={this.captureInput}
                onBlur={this.focusContainer} // or                 onBlur={() => setTimeout(() => this.focusContainer(), 0) } - why ?

                ref={this.container}
                // tabIndex is needed for focus/blur to work on non input type elements.
                tabIndex={0}
            >
              <img src={scanTag} style={{maxWidth: '100%'}} alt='scan tag via scanner' />
          ..........
    </div>
       )
    }
}
```